# Gaps between words in bibliography

Tags: natbib

I am getting awkward gaps in the bibliography while citing online news articles.

```
@MISC{DHLHYBRID,
   author =       { Kastrenakes, Jacob},
   title =        {{UPS} has a delivery truck that can launch a drone},
   editor =       {theverge.com},
   month =        {February},
   year =         {2017},
   url = {https://www.theverge.com/2017/2/21/14691062/ups-drone-delivery-truck-test-completed-video},
   note = {\emph{https://www.theverge.com/2017/2/21/14691062/ups-drone-delivery-truck-test-completed-video} {[Online; posted 21-February-2017]}},
```

It looks like this [image]

I see huge gaps before UPS and before and after "J" in author's name.

A normal bibliography looks like this:
[image]

Comment: your biblioraphy style should generate `\url{http....}` so the url will linebreak but you have provided no usable example to allow anyone to reproduce the problem

Comment: But it's a fair bet 'tex-core' is not the right tag. @DavidCarlisle Biblatex handles URLs badly by default for me, though usually it lets them spill off the page rather than leaving gaps. Does it do better by default for you?

Comment: You appear to be putting the URL into `note` as well as `url,` and it appears to be the note field which is typesetting it. But you don't use `\url` there, so obviously, it isn't handled properly. However, Biblatex handles `url` fields` OK(ish), so it is not obvious why you've blocked that and pushed `note`. Are you actually using Biblatex at all?

Comment: I am using sharelatex, I believe the bibliography would be same in that as well.

Comment: I am using natbib, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should (a) replace the `\emph` in the note by `\url` and (b) load the `url` package.  In your particular case passing the `hyphens` option to the `url` package, so allowing breaks in the url at hyhens, gives best results.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{DHLHYBRID}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

with `test.bib`

```
@Misc{DHLHYBRID,
  author =   {Kastrenakes, Jacob},
  title =    {{UPS} has a delivery truck that can launch a drone},
  editor =   {theverge.com},
  month =    {February},
  year =     2017,
  note =
                  {\url{https://www.theverge.com/2017/2/21/14691062/ups-drone-delivery-truck-test-completed-video}
                  {[Online; posted 21-February-2017]}}
}
```

The large spaces your saw in your original example are the result of LaTeX trying to stretch as much as possible to fill up the first line as it fails to find good break points later in the paragraph.  The `\url` command that `natbib` styles provide is usually just `\texttt` which does not allow such breaks.  The `\url` command from the `url` package (or from `hyperef`) allows breaking of non-word objects such as url's across lines, and thus gives more options for how LaTeX can break up the paragraph.  Seeing the [documentation of the `url` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) for further options, including ways to change the font used for the url.

Note that you could alternatively use the `url` field as follows in `test.bib`:

```
@Misc{DHLHYBRID,
  author =   {Kastrenakes, Jacob},
  title =    {{UPS} has a delivery truck that can launch a drone},
  editor =   {theverge.com},
  month =    {February},
  year =     2017,
  url =
                  {https://www.theverge.com/2017/2/21/14691062/ups-drone-delivery-truck-test-completed-video},
  note =     {[Online; posted 21-February-2017]}
}
```

but now the url will be proceeded by `URL` and you will still need to load the `url` package to get good spacing.